# How can I decode the following bytes?

Tags: python, byte, decode

```
>>> byte_code = b'\x01\x00^\x00H6\x00#'

>>> byte_code.decode("utf-8")
'\x01\x00^\x00H6\x00#'
```

This doesn't seem to work in Python. Shouldn't the result be string?

Comment: Shouldn't? Well... Shouldn't you know what the result should be?

Comment: no i don't but i am guessing string

Comment: Why do you feel the result is not a string?

Comment: `type(byte_code.decode("utf-8"))` says: `<class 'str'>`

Comment: i am looking for something more meaningful

Comment: Meaningful than what? I am now confused.

Comment: The first two escapes are unprintable characters anyway. I suspect it would decode to '^H6#' (without quotes):

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score -2):

Python is higher level than C or C++ language and it is not the best language to work with bits and bytes. It has no any data type considering bytes and bits so the only way to work with them is to use packages implemented on C or C++ such as https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/. However Python is able to represent bits and bytes using strings so you basically right. I am not sure what you exactly mean by word "decode" but try this:

`print('{}'.format('\x01\x00^\x00H6\x00#'))`

Comment: It might be a good idea to learn about the meaning of the `b` in the question. It is actually such a representation of bytes you are missing in Python.